Android notification action not clickable while it is continuously updating
So I have an download progress notification on android with two actions, "cancel" and "pause".
When the notification is updating fast the action button of the notification is not responsive, so I must click it multiple times to trigger it.
I understand why it happens: when I try to click it, and press down, at the moment I lift up the finger it's already a different notification since it updated and since I need two actions, down and then up, it never happens.
What are the ways i can fix this?
I tried to set the notification as onGoing(true) but that did not helped.

Make sure you update the notification with intervals of time, like: each10 percent update notification.

I've observed this as well, with a countdown notification that is updated every second. It seems the user can't press the button because the notification has been updated and redrawn by the time they release the button. Looking for a solution!
